# Update local branch with new PR changes

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull-request, pull

Another member on my team has made a PR, which I am writing tests for. I pulled his changes and I am working on them locally.

I have made a significant amount of changes locally (I have not pushed them yet since I am not done). The other member has since updated the PR with changes to files that I have not touched, but I need to pull them into my local branch so that my code is up to date when I push the final changes.

When I try a `git pull` I am told the following:

```
hint: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
hint: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
hint: commands sometime before your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
Already up to date.
```

How do I resolve this? I want to pull whatever changes he made and keep my changes to the code base. There would be no merge conflicts since he worked on completely different files than I did.

Comment: Normally such thing should not happen but you can just use "git config -- global pull.rebase false" and then run "git pull"

Comment: did one of you actually start work from the same branch or both of you create the same branch independently from different commits ?

Comment: "How do I resolve this?" -> you pick one of three options suggested by the hint message. "Already up to date." suggests that you already have all the remote changes. Lastly, make sure that you have the latest version of Git installed (IIRC there was a bug with (non-)ff pulls recently)

Comment: What are you asking to be resolved? The long "hint" stuff is currently just a warning (and you turn it off exactly how the hint says).

Comment: @Dmitry he created the branch to work on. I just pulled it yesterday, and since then he made changes. Does your solution still work?

Comment: @William Johnson yes it does